# How to check for "↵" (new line) when comparing on browser?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a element.innerText that has a new line in the middle of it:

When I print it as an array, I get that in the console:

`myArray = ["a", "b", "c", "↵", "d", "e", "f"]`

How can I check for the "↵" position?

Like:

```
if (myArray === "↵") { // This doesn't work
 do something...
}
```

Comment: Do you mean a linebreak? In that case check for `'\n'`

Comment: Do you mean a new line or do you mean a Downwards Arrow with Corner Leftwards?

Comment: Whatever that caracter is, using `indexOf()` should help.

Comment: This "↵" gets printed how? `console.log(array[index]);` ? Anyway, "\n" == NEWLINE, "\r" == CARRIAGE RETURN.

Comment: I mean a new line. It's inside a `div` with `contenteditable`, but that's how my browser printed it (chrome). I tried checking for '/n' and no luck. I will edit and post a snippet here.

Comment: @cbdev420 your slash is the other way around and it is important.

Comment: @ThiefMaster '\n' works! I was using the wrong slash. Can you write an answer with that advice? I'll accept that! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for `\n`.. `\n` is the new line for javascript.

So try `console.log(myArray.indexOf("\n"));`